# How can I enable Radeon R7 M260/M265/M340/M360 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics, integrated

I have just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and `lspci -nn` reports:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
...
09:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360] [1002:6900] (rev ff)
```

If I run `glxinfo` instead I get:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
```

How can I enable my R7 GPU and use it? Am I supposed to use the **AMDGPU** driver? Any suggestion to get decent *OpenGL* acceleration?
I don't want to use the integrated *i5*...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I should prefix any 3d program I want the *Topaz XT* to be used with `DRI_PRIME=1 <command>`.

Too bad this locks up the system but that's another problem.